# Adding prometheus alerting rules to grafana

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, grafana-loki, grafana-alerts

I'm desperate with activating alerts in grafana (running in k8s).

- Are there standard alerts (like a default file or so), which I can import into grafana?
  For instance for getting notified when there is something with the k8s cluster?
- I've downloaded a file from [awesome-prometheus-alerts](https://awesome-prometheus-alerts.grep.to/rules.html), which provides a starting set of rules. According to the grafana doc, it can also be used in grafana.

Unfortunately, I'm unable to get it running. Any ideas, how this can be accomplished?

Our setting:

- We are using helm for deploying
- Use of loki-stack

  - Configurations are being made in a values.yml file, overwriting values in grafana.ini

Answer (score 0):

Grafana Loki supports prometheus queries and you can update the queries in values.yaml file and apply it for getting the changes applied. Follow this [document](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/installation/helm/monitor-and-alert/) for more information. If you want the list of promQl queries follow this [document](https://www.containiq.com/post/promql-cheat-sheet-with-examples).

Comment: Thanks, I'll check this out and respond here.

Comment: @Peter is your issue resolved? Upvote or accept this solution so that it will be helpful for remaining community members.